# Why does a CURL command line with JSON data specified on the command line not work in a Windows command prompt window?

Tags: curl, cmd

I am sending a **POST** request in `postman` and it is working.
But it's giving me error whenever I am using my `cmd` using `curl` command.

Condition is that I want to use curly braces in my password.

Request body: `{"username":"myself", "password":"shj}hai"}`

Url: `http://localhost:8080/auth`

In a Windows command prompt window I am executing:

```
curl -H 'Content-Length: 200' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"myself", "password":"shj}hai"}' http://localhost:8080/auth
```

I am getting output the error:

```
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 36:
```

I was expecting a response from my program using **CMD**.

Can there be any other way using `cmd`?

It worked by using " instead of ' and then using escape character as ^ for whole json string.